# UCanAccess: reading calculated fields with "^" operator

Tags: java, exponent, ucanaccess, calculation

I´m using UCanAccess to read data from an MS Access database into my Java tool. Every table/query is read correctly, except one query containing a field that calculates the power of a value with the "^" operator. I then get the "UCAExc:::4.0.3 user lacks privilege or object not found: -Queryname- " message.

Reading any other calculated fields from the same query works fine, only as soon as I use the "^" operator it fails.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with a simple test table under UCanAccess 4.0.3. Please post your issue in the [UCanAccess help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/) and include a sample database file ([mcve]) that can be used to demonstrate the problem.